# Flutter Horizontal CustomScrollView with Snap & Floating

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

Is there any way to build a Sliver widget that functions like SliverAppBar? SliverAppBar doesn't work well with a CustomScrollView when scrollDirection is horizontal. I want to have a widget where snap and float is true, but pinned is false. For that reason, I don't think StickyHeader is a good option.

Essentially I'm looking to make a widget like SliverAppBar where scrolling to the left shows an iconButton and scrolling all the way to the start extends that IconButton into a Flat/Raised Button (Where this would be the flexibleSpace).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I realized I could just use PersistentSliverHeader and set floating to true.